Plotting `pc@graph` from `pcalg`
A while ago I run a pcalg::ps model which I have visualised via igraph:
library(MASS)
library(pcalg)
library(igraph)

# Some variance-covariance
Corrs <- matrix(c(1.0,0.6,0.7,0.5,0.6,1.0,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.5,1.0,0.7,0.5,0.6,0.7,1.0), 4, 4)
SDs <- c(1.0,0.5,2.0,1.0)
Covs <- SDs %*% t(SDs) * Corrs

dat = as.data.frame(mvrnorm(100, mu=c(0,0,0,0), Sigma=Covs))

n = nrow(dat)
V = colnames(dat) # node names
pc1 = pc(suffStat=list(C=cor(dat), n=n),
             indepTest=gaussCItest, # indep.test: partial correlations
             alpha=0.05, labels=V, u2pd='retry')

gr = as(pc1@graph, 'igraph')

plot.igraph(gr, layout=layout_in_circle,
    vertex.label=V, vertex.shape='circle', vertex.size=30,
    vertex.label.cex=0.55, vertex.label.color='black',
    edge.arrow.size=0.6)

Unfortunately, it seems that as(pc1@graph, 'igraph') does not work anymore:
Error in as(pc.total@graph, "igraph") : 
  no method or default for coercing “graphNEL” to “igraph”

Is there a way around that would solve the problem?
Alternatively, what would be the best way forward to plot from the pc object?

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

I would do it, otherwise, but I cannot get the plot. If you think it would help, I could try to downgrade these two packages and try this again. Should I?

It's not clear at all what exactly you want in this plot. Nor it is clear how you created your pc object used in this example. If I copy/paste the code as written I get an error that says "there is no package called ‘graph’". I don't know what pc is supposed to contain in this case. The package does seem to depend on some bioconductor packages. Might need to make sure those are installed separately.

I failed to downgrade the two packages and make them run. The code did run about a year ago.
However, I now made a complete reproducible example.

There has been  a major update of the igraph package recently. Look at the doc. Perhaps you want graph_from_graphnel or as_graphnel.
